# Strange WP menu behavior and calculating an offset height for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two parts to a script that calculates the height of the header and jumbotron to set an offset height, and then in part one:

```
var offsetHeight = "";
```

opens a bootstrap tab when triggered from an external link and scrolls to the offset...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function navHash() {
        var hash = document.location.hash;
        if (hash) {
            history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
            $('.nav-stacked a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
            offsetHeight = $('header').outerHeight() + $('.jumbotron').outerHeight();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: offsetHeight
            }, 50);
        }
    }
    navHash();
    $(window).on('hashchange', navHash)
});
```

The next part just simply repeats the scroll behavior when a tab link is clicked and a new tab is opened.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    offsetHeight = $('header').outerHeight() + $('.jumbotron').outerHeight();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetHeight
    }, 50);
})
```

I am still a little stumped on this because this all works fine in the static version of the site. But when put into the Wordpress template, it breaks. What seems to be happening is that the "drop down" items in the menu for the WP version are expanding and then collapsing once the page is finally rendered. You can see this when you load the site on a slow connection, or in my case I had to added a javascript alert in order to pause the page rendering at the "document ready" state. What you see as a result is the the navigation height being like 900+ pixels with the dropdown items expanded. As soon as you close the alert, the items collapse into the dropdown and the page renders as normal. The script above animates the page to the wrong location because the calculated offset height (at document ready) of the header and the jumbotron is wrong. This behavior seems to be due to WP making a database query to generate the menu. This would explain why we didn't see this in the static version of the site, as the menu links are hard-coded into the HTML.

Comment: Can you please share the Url ?

Comment: It looks like jquery/javascript is applying the `display:none` to the dropdowns `ul` element. The HTML is loading faster than the javascript so there is a flash when the dropdown is visible. Try applying display none the "sub-menu dropdown-menu" `ul` in your CSS. That should solve the header problem you are having at least.

Comment: @SandraWillford Sorry I am stumped :/ Maybe put your alert back in and then inspect the dropdown element to see why it is being shown briefly on load.

Comment: @WizardCoder your solution worked, although in the conversion process from static to WP an additional class was added to the dropdown menu that was overriding my "display: none". Its all working now thank you. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes :)

Comment: @SandraWillford Yeah, I know what you mean :P Sometimes I stop being able to see the wood from the trees.